# How can I send pusher beams browser notification alerts with nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, service-worker, pusher, pusher-js

I'm implementing Pusher-Beams with next.js using authenticated users flow exactly as described in beams docs, and I got in the browser console `client is subscribed and registered successfully`.

However at pusher-beams debug-console website page I have these messages when I click on push notification button and **nothing shown in my application**,

[image]

I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong here?!! and why I keep getting device `de-registered` message?

Note: I've tried with Chrome, Firefox and Brave but it is not working.

Comment: same issue ... did you figure how to solve it ?

Comment: @MohammedALMahmoOd sorry to disappoint you, but no I haven't found any solution.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you know how to solve it?

Comment: @AfifAlfiano sorry to disappoint you, but no I haven't found any solution.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanGad Hey Abdal, It's okay, the problem with my application is that my settings on the operating system are blocking the notification from chrome.

Comment: @AfifAlfiano great to hear that you solved it.